# COBOL Connection to Server got closed in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, cobol

I'm trying to learn COBOL to (hopefully) help with the crisis right now. I'm taking the [IBM course](https://github.com/openmainframeproject/cobol-programming-course/issues) which requires the "IBM Zowe Open Editor" and "Zowe Explorer" extensions in VSCode. It took me a long time to set up the JDK for it.I'm using JDK1.8.0_251 like the [configuration](https://ibm.github.io/zopeneditor-about/Docs/getting_started.html#configuring-java-for-ibm-z-open-editor) asked. I'm still getting an error saying "the cobol language server crashed 5 times in the last 3 miuntes" rendering my code unable to run. Here is the output for the COBOL language server:

```
[Info  - 10:22:35 AM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
[Info  - 10:22:57 AM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
[Info  - 10:23:20 AM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
[Error - 10:23:22 AM] Request textDocument/definition failed.
  Message: Internal error.
  Code: -32603 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.lambda$null$0(GenericEndpoint.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.request(GenericEndpoint.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.handleRequest(RemoteEndpoint.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.consume(RemoteEndpoint.java:190)
    at com.ibm.lsp.cobol.core.abilities.WatchLSPParent.lambda$0(WatchLSPParent.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.handleMessage(StreamMessageProducer.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.listen(StreamMessageProducer.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.ConcurrentMessageProcessor.run(ConcurrentMessageProcessor.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.lambda$null$0(GenericEndpoint.java:65)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.lsp.cobol.core.handlers.GetDefinitionHandler.getDefinition(GetDefinitionHandler.java:34)
    at com.ibm.lsp.cobol.core.CobolLanguageServer.definition(CobolLanguageServer.java:182)
    ... 17 more

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
[Info  - 10:23:42 AM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
[Error - 10:24:05 AM] Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.
```

Update: I think I need access to a z/OS mainframe. I found out how to get free access [here](http://mtm2019.mybluemix.net/index.html) at IBM's Master the Mainframe program, but apparently I need either z/OSMF software added (which only gives you a 3 day free trial) or this thing called the Remote System Explorer API. I'll keeping looking into it...

Comment: your update is correct. If you primarily want to look at COBOL I suggest to use another plugin: vscode_cobol and a machine-local compiler, for example [GnuCOBOL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnucobol/) - the plugin also allows to be configured for using it directly for compilation, see its documentation

Answer (score 0):

The COBOL server system was unavailable at the time in the report for data center upgrades.  COBOL server is up now.  I recommend using the Open Mainframe Project, OMP, slack channel cobol-programming-course for assistance.  FYI - z/OSMF is installed and operational.  The COBOL course system, the Master the Mainframe Learning System, Zowe Tutorial System, and ZTrial system are all separate z/OS with separate IP address.  Please include ID and IP address of system to be certain we are in sync.